# Fatou's lemma applicability in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$; let $g: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$;
let $f_{n}: t \mapsto g(\varphi (n), t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Then under suitable conditions we have
$$
\int \liminf_{n \to \infty}f_{n} \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int f_{n}
$$
by Fatou's lemma.
I would like to ask if today the liminf is taken instead with respect to the argument $\varphi (n)$, what is a conclusion we can draw similar to the integral inequality? Specifically, do we still have
$\int g(\liminf_{n \to \infty}\varphi (n), \cdot) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int g(\varphi_{n}, \cdot)$ to a certain extent?

Answer (score 0):

Without continuity of $g$, we have no reason to think $g(\liminf_{n \to \infty }\varphi(n), \cdot)$ is related in any way to $g(\varphi(n), \cdot)$.

Comment: Hello, I guess I deliberately imposed no assumptions on any functions involved to potentially allow the most general result related. You are welcome to provide any information; thanks.